# How create functionality of servlet filter using Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel, servlet-filters

I need to have a route be the first and last that is executed the same as you would get using a servlet filter. Is there any way in Camel to do this so I have access to the exchange? Or possibly a way to have onCompletion only execute once right before the response is built?

Answer (score 1):

The on completion has a `BeforeConsumer` mode which you can use to do stuff just before the consumer writes back the response: http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html

And for in the start of the route, then use interceptFrom, or an event listener, or route policy or something else. There is several ways with Camel.

Comment: The onCompletion with BeforeConsumer is triggered at the end of every route - so if I have a route that calls another route it can be triggered multiple times. I need something to work like a servlet filter. InterceptFrom appears to work fine for the incoming though.